# Angular 12 - Check a service all the time, is it feasible?

Tags: angular

I have a component "topbar.component.ts" where I want to call a service that is checking if I have a running process, if I have a running process the response will be the next property:

```
"isExecution": true
```

In this case, the aforementioned component shows me an icon of the running process but if:

```
"isExecution": false
```

It shows me a icon that allow me to launch again a process.

Summarizing, a service in a component that is checking every second, for example, if I have a running process to show one icon or another, if the value of the service's response is false, it shows me an icon that allows me to launch the process again by clicking on it. but if the response is true it will be a processing icon and nothing can be done about the icon, only to wait the finish for to recover status of icon initial that to allow to lunch a new process.

NOTE: I'm not sure if it would be detrimental or bad practice to have a service constantly checking the status of a run. Since it would be interesting to only activate it when a process is launched, which is done from another component called "execution.component.ts" they are launched from this component, but from "topbar.component.ts" it is only checked if this is in action. This would be ideal, but if it's feasible to have a service doing the checks, it would save me hassle.

What would be the best way to do this in Angular? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by simply [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function, this would run after every x milliseconds. But as you have asked the `Angular` way to do it then I would suggest to use [interval](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html) from `rxjs` like so;

```
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

subscription: Subscription;

...

//emit value in sequence every 10 second
const source = interval(10000);
const isExecution: Boolean = true;
this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => this.opensnack(isExecution));

...

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: I knew that with setInterval it was one way, but I wanted to know if there was any other better way, but I'll do it as you told me, thanks